# Lighttpd ldap auth issue, massive performance loss (lighttpd 1.4.35-1.el6.x86_64 + RHEL 6.6)

Tags: redhat, ldap, lighttpd, epel, mod-auth

I installed lighttpd for the first time from epel repo.

I changed user and group for the webserver and ran the lighttpd server.
I can download a page with 200 small images in about a second.

If I enable ldap authentication with configuring ldap and adding the below, the requests start taking up to a minute with 5 second pause showing in firebug.

```
auth.require = ("/" =>
(
"method" => "basic",
"realm" => "here",
"require" => "valid-user"
)
)
```

Is this a known issue? I've tried about everything and I cannot make this issue go away.

Apache handled ~equivalent auth config without such issues.

The auth is working though. Prompt comes up and it accepts only correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the following could be your issue here

"When loaded together with mod_fastcgi, mod_auth must be loaded before mod_fastcgi. Or else users will experience long delays when login in and sysadmins will probably not find out the source of the problem due to the lack of meaningful error messages."

From the Lighttpd documentation (https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModAuth#ldap)